# Как передать параметр из метода Chrome API во вне?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Метод получает response. Все ок.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
alert(response); 
});
```

Как передать параметр response во вне метода?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
response = response; 
});

alert(response); //тут response is not defined :(
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: А вы пробовали вызвать 'alert' внутри слушателя? У гугла есть проблемы с переопределение переменных вне его методов.

Comment: @Илья, причем тут гугл то ? Просто событие вызывает обработчик, **после** того, как выполнится текущий поток. Так устроен мир. Вот если вы на почту придете и скажите "когда придет посылка, положите ее в этот абон ящик и позвоните мне", а потом сразу побежите проверять ящик и начнёте возмущаться, что посылки там нет. Это будет проблема роспочты или недосмотр санитаров ?

Comment: @zb' я неправильно выразился, в Chrome API после выполнения текущего потока во внешнем alert'е всегда будет response is not defined, в данном случае для передачи данных наружу нужно либо использовать колбэки, либо записывать эти данные в какой-нибудь storage.

Comment: @Илья это не "проблема" Chrome API, так работает JavaScript.